# How to disallow submit form if condition is false

Tags: jquery, submit

Situation:

```
<script>
    ...
    $('#trollMeNow').on('click', function () {
        if(condition)
            {
                SubmitThisFormNow();
            }
            else
            {
                BlockSubmitThisForm(); // <--- how to do that??
            }
    });
</script>
<input type="submit" id="trollMeNow"/>
```

I want to cancel submitting the form if condition returns false. How to do that?

Comment: use return false in else block

Comment: Why are you not using form submit event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
$('#trollMeNow').on('click', function () {

    if (condition) {
        SubmitThisFormNow();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#trollMeNow').on('click', function (e) {
  if(condition)
   {
    SubmitThisFormNow();
   }
   else
   {
    e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i hope you just created all function inside **condition()**

Use the `if` statment like below

```
if(condition)
        {
            SubmitThisFormNow();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Place following in the else condition:

```
document.getElementById("trollMeNow").disabled=true;
```